# how to wrap a text in react native ios.? In android it is wrapping within the flex width but in ios not wrapping

Tags: react-native

i need to wrap the text inside a flex:
i searched last four days but i dint get any solutions. if anybody knows please help me>
Thank you in advance
 Some text to wrap inside the flex view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android the text is wrapping but in iOS there if there is no height to wrap the text means the text will won't wrap. So that we have to give height to the text tag then it ill wrap the text